# Else-If statements in JavaScript seem to cause some odd behaviour in Moment.js weekdays

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.JS to check whether the current day is not a Sunday or a Saturday. If it isn't, then do some operation.

Here's my code:

```
let currentDay = moment().weekday();

if(currentDay !== 0 || currentDay !== 6){
     doSomeOperation();
  } else { console.log("we should get here on a Sunday"); }
```

This to me makes complete sense - if currentDay is not Sunday or Saturday then `doSomeOperation();` (For context, I'm running this on a Sunday.)

However, it fails and it runs the `doSomeOperation();` method in the `if` block. I've run this in every combination possible but it still fails. I then decided to run them separately.

```
if(currentDay !== 0){
         doSomeOperation();
  } else { console.log('you should get here'); }
```

This succeeds - I get to the `else` block. This makes no sense - because if that succeeded, then why did the above fail?

I finally changed it round to this:

```
if ((currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 6)){
console.log('you should get here');
} else { doSomeOperation() }
```

This succeeds and I print out 'you should get here'. If I invert the operators then all the checks pass. My question is what is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a logical AND in the condition, because you want to exclude both days.

```
if (currentDay !== 0 && currentDay !== 6) {
    // do some operations
}
```

To negate the condition, you could apply [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if (currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 6) {
    // saturday or sunday
} else {
    // other days
    // do some operations
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nina - thanks for your reply. Why was it when I inverted the operators, they all worked with the logical OR?

Comment: it does not work with equal and or, because every part is sometimes `true` and the condition is always `true`.

Comment: When I'm having trouble with if statements, I always try turning them into questions to see if they make sense. If I can't then there's usually a problem with the code. Or the code is just too complicated and needs to be broken down.

Comment: @MaxBilbow, oyu could take a table of truth and do by pen and paper a check, what is going to work for you.